# SilverStripe Fluent menu template

Tags: php, silverstripe

The SilverStripe Fluent module has a ready-made template to display a simple language switching menu on the front-end.

```
<% loop Locales %>
 <li class="$LinkingMode">
  <a href="$Link.ATT" hreflang="$LocaleRFC1766"<% end_if %>>
   $Title.XML
  </a>
 </li>
<% end_loop %>
```

**When it loops "Locales" what is it technically looping?** There is no Database table called "Locales".

My goal is to eventually find the variable (or write the function) that returns the language abbreviation (not the country!). So I need something that returns for example `nl` rather than `nl-NL` (as `$LocaleRFC1766` returns).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Locales` is a function](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/code/extensions/FluentExtension.php#L320-L327) in the `FluentExtension` extension:

```
/**
 * Templatable list of all locales
 *
 * @return ArrayList
 */
public function Locales()
{
    $data = array();
    foreach (Fluent::locales() as $locale) {
        $data[] = $this->owner->LocaleInformation($locale);
    }
    return new ArrayList($data);
}
```

This is the data that is returned by the [`LocaleInformation` function](https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/code/extensions/FluentExtension.php#L379-L412):

```
$data = array(
    'Locale' => $locale,
    'LocaleRFC1766' => i18n::convert_rfc1766($locale),
    'Alias' => Fluent::alias($locale),
    'Title' => i18n::get_locale_name($locale),
    'LanguageNative' => Fluent::locale_native_name($locale),
    'Language' => i18n::get_lang_from_locale($locale),
    'Link' => $link,
    'AbsoluteLink' => $link ? Director::absoluteURL($link) : null,
    'LinkingMode' => $linkingMode
);
```

`Language` was recently added to allow for retrieving just the language abbreviation.

To make use of this we can create a custom `LocaleMenu.ss` template that uses the `$Language` variable:

```
<% if $Locales %>
<div class="left">Locale <span class="arrow">&rarr;</span>
    <nav class="primary">
        <ul>
            <% loop $Locales %>
                <li class="$LinkingMode">
                    <a href="$Link.ATT" <% if $LinkingMode != 'invalid' %>rel="alternate" hreflang="$Language"<% end_if %>>$Title.XML</a>
                </li>
            <% end_loop %>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: Fantastic, worked. I see your pull request made it to the Master as well.